# How to restart a printer job?

Tags: 18.04, printing

I just upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. Also just changed all printer cartridges. System76 Oryx Pro, Brother MFC-J470DW. I don't know if this is a printer problem, but Brother's support system doesn't address this and there seems to be no way to ask them.

Problems: colors are off, can't do maintenance routines.

I can do a simple Print Test Page and print from LO writer.

It seems to have a problem producing reds and grays. In the screen print below, the top section with ubuntu's normal dark purple prints as a fuzzy black, and everything below that has a greenish tinge.

I want to do the self-test and clean heads jobs, but whenever I submit them, a small window says the job completed, but the queue shows them as "stopped". Terminal command fg %[#] for these jobs return "no such job".

What can I do?

[image: Screen print for printer problem]

UPDATE: This is output from the localhost URL below, Jobs tab. A little more information -- but **why is "Clean" an invalid command?** I've done it before. Not often, but before. I'm just using the GUI, not fiddling with line command parms. I'm not a programmer, but if there's another way to give the printer a command, I don't know the syntax, and wouldn't the command just be to "clean" it?

[image: localhost output]

Comment: In a browser enter http://localhost:631/ to run CUPS and check options in there.

Answer (score 0):

The spooled file can be viewed, printed, copied, etc.

The spooled file for CUPS request 123 is:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ type cupsname
cupsname is a function
cupsname () 
{ 
    printf "%05d" "$1"
}
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /var/spool/cups/d$(cupsname 123)-001
```

For the non-programmer:

Point your web browser to `http://localhost:631/jobs` (respond with your login userid and password, when prompted). Click the buttons "`Show Completed Jobs`" or "`Show All Jobs`"[image: http://localhost:631/jobs]

Comment: Sorry I'm not a programmer.